# A word for someone that deflects compliment?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for a type of person that responds to a compliment by complaining about it(as an attempt to deflect this compliment)?

e.g. *Mark: Hey dude! Your new haircut looks pretty sick!*

*Dave(who thinks it's pretty good himself): Nah.. The hairdresser should've done a better job on the sides*

Comment: Bashful or fishing for more compliments.

Comment: I think he may just be too modest and may not know how to take a compliment.

Comment: Agree with @Jim.  Modest, or maybe humble.

Answer (score 5):

*[self-deprecating](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-deprecating)*

> Belittling or undervaluing oneself; excessively modest.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-deprecation)

> Self-deprecation is the act of reprimanding oneself by belittling, undervaluing, or disparaging oneself,[1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-deprecating) or being excessively modest.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-deprecation)[3] It can be used in humor and tension release.[4]

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe they are just **humble** and dont want to get a big ego...

Answer (score -7):

Words that come to mind:
["superficial"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/superficial)
["Ostensible"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ostensible)

> A superficial person who denies praise despite believing it to be true themselves.
>
> A person with ostensible humility, when in truth their opinion of themselves (themself?) is high.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestions are much better than what I'd thought of, lol.

Comment: A *superficial* person is someone who is shallow, or who does not or cannot intellectualize an understanding of something beyond what is obvious or visceral. People cannot be *ostensible* any more than they can be *purported* or *supposed*. Please explain why you believe these words would suit the questioner, and ideally include examples from literature or quality journalism.

Comment: [You wondered in meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10223/why-is-this-answer-not-suited-to-the-question) why this answer is being downvoted. Only those who downvoted can speak for themselves, but we can at least try. I think these two words don't fit the OPs request. Analytically, yes, both these share something about appearances which is implied by 'deflecting a compliment', but neither superficial or ostensible capture anything else about that situation, and that situation isn't primarily about appearances.

Comment: And on the other side, by intuition, neither of these words fits because deflecting involves deeper thought than connoted by the surface connotations of superficial and ostensible. So both words are just not appropriate and would be very misleading in the OP's situation.